# Highcharts issue updating chart type: not recognizing highcharts functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to update my current highchart that I have to a new chart type, however I am having difficulty doing so.

I have embedded javascript in my page, the following is below

```
<script>


chart = $(function () {
    $('#chart_example').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Traffic'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['November', 'December', 'January']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Views'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Hello',
            data: [50, 30, 60]
        }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have the following two scripts below at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
....
<script src="custom_script"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the custom script, I want to update the highcharts library from a line graph into a bar graph. I looked at the API and found an [update method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update)
that takes in new options. So I tried the following:

```
$(document).on('click' , '#button' , function() {
     var options = new Object();
      options.chart = new Object();
      options.chart.type = 'bar';
      options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
      chart.update(options, true);
      //the container the chart is in
      $('#chart_example').show();
...
```

However I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: chart.update is not a function(anonymous function) @ custom_script=1:41m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

My thought was that the order of the javascript is wrong but I seem to have the javascript in the right order. My questions are then:

1) Is this chart variable set correctly? My understanding is that a variable that is unset with var is automatically global.
2) What is the cause of this error and how do I fix it so that it updates properly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2j1g200g/29/

```
var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: 'chart_example'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Traffic'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['November', 'December', 'January']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Views'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Hello',
            data: [50, 30, 60]
        }]
    };
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
options.chart.type = 'bar';
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this, it should get what you want. I included a button for demonstration.

```js
chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Traffic'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['November', 'December', 'January']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Views'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Hello',
    data: [50, 30, 60]
  }]
};

$('#chart_example').highcharts(chartOptions);


$(document).on('click' , '#button' , function() {
  chartOptions.chart.type = 'bar';    
  $('#chart_example').highcharts(chartOptions);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">rechart</button>
<div id="chart_example"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```